# ASP.NET Core 2 - GetUserIdAsync returning null Result with Guid Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I'm currently porting a site to ASP.NET Core 2 and am getting the following Exception thrown when I call `userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user)` with a user class that extends `IdentityUser<Guid>`:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1.<GenerateAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
```

[`GenerateAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Identity/DataProtectionTokenProvider.cs#L66) makes a call to [`UserManager.GetUserIdAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Stores/UserStoreBase.cs#L117), which is returning the `null` value in `Result`, which `Write()` is complaining about, even though the `User` instance I'm passing through has `07c0423e-f36b-1410-8007-800000000000` in `Id`.

If I call `userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user)` directly on the same `UserManager` instance on which I'm calling `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync()` I get this same `null` value in `Result`.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

**Edit**: As requested, a functional example can be found at [github.com/BenjaminNolan/GetUserIdAsyncNullExample](https://github.com/BenjaminNolan/GetUserIdAsyncNullExample)

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos I've uploaded a 'working' example at https://github.com/BenjaminNolan/GetUserIdAsyncNullExample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is with [these lines](https://github.com/BenjaminNolan/GetUserIdAsyncNullExample/blob/master/GetUserIdAsyncNullExample/Models/User.cs#L15) from your `User` class:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[DefaultValue("NEWSEQUENTIALID()")]
new public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Your use of the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) here is suppressing the following compiler warning:

> 'User.Id' hides inherited member 'IdentityUser.Id'.

This warning informs you that if you access `Id` via a `User` reference (rather than e.g. a `IdentityUser<Guid>` reference - the base class), you will be working with a *different* `Id` property. You can see what this looks like if you inspect the value of `user.Id` in your controller and compare that with the value of `((IdentityUser<Guid>)user).Id` (casting to the base class in order to access *its* `Id` property).

It's easy to fix in your case - just remove the `Id` property from your `User` class: you've already specified that the existing `Id` property from `IdentityUser<TKey>` will be of type `Guid` and its already configured to be the key, etc.